# New parse.com php API - currentUser not giving back a user

Tags: php, parse-platform

I am able to login with user credentials with

```
try {
  $user = ParseUser::logIn("myname", "mypass");
  // Do stuff after successful login.
} catch (ParseException $error) {
  // The login failed. Check error to see why.
}
```

but if I try to get the currentUser afterwards with

```
$currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();
if ($currentUser) {
    // do stuff with the user
} else {
    // show the signup or login page
}
```

$currentUser is not set.

I suspect this more to be a php "issue" that I don't know. I am greatful for any hint for keeping currentUser retained in my code as long I do not log out.

Comment: I've never used the parse library, but looks like a session issue... Did you check if session is started by the library or is it you that must start it?

Comment: Oh, who can read... "By default, whenever you use any signup or login methods, the user will be saved in PHP Session storage (The $_SESSION superglobal.)". Now I only have to know the name of the session... THANKS FOR YOU QUICK REPLY.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order for the getCurrentUser() method to work, you must define the type of session storage to use. You can use the ParseSessionStorage class to achieve this:

```
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseSessionStorage;

session_start();

// Init parse: app_id, rest_key, master_key
ParseClient::initialize('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz');

// set session storage
ParseClient::setStorage( new ParseSessionStorage() );

try {
  $user = ParseUser::logIn("myname", "mypass");
  // Do stuff after successful login.
} catch (ParseException $error) {
  // The login failed. Check error to see why.
}

$currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();

print_r( $currentUser );
```

Comment: GREAT! That is what I was missing. Thank you. I now have to see how I can access (perform queries) from user restricted classes, since now I am able to read only from classes which have no user restrictions and get results. I use ACL in my iOS App and I try to figure out how to set defaultACL in php to access them. In Javascript this was very easy, in php I don't know yet. But again, GREAT THANKS!