# Parse PHP Session Not Stored

Tags: php, session, parse-platform

So i'm trying to create a parse login with php and i'm having some issues. I can login succesfull and print the session data. But when i refresh the page all the data is gone and i get redirected back to my login page. Here is the code of the two files:

Index.php

```
<?php

require 'autoload.php';

session_start();
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseUser;

ParseClient::initialize('myapi',    
                        'myapi', 
                        'myapi');

print_r($_SESSION);
$currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();


if ($currentUser) {

} else {
   header('Location: login.php');
}
```

?>

login.php

```
<?php

require 'autoload.php';
session_start();
use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseException;



ParseClient::initialize('myapi',    
                        'myapi', 
                        'myapi');


$currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();
 print_r($_SESSION);
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{ 
    if(isset($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'])) 
    {     
        $username = trim($_POST['user']); 
        $password = trim($_POST['pass']); 

        try {
        $user = ParseUser::logIn($username, $password);
        header('Location: index.php');
        } catch (ParseException $error) {

        }
    } 
} else {

    if ($currentUser) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
       // 
    }
}
```

?>

Can someone please help me with this problem?

RDV

Comment: As i know that session_start() must be in the first line of each file.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a bit late but I had the same problem as you. The Parse PHP docs are not that well covered and they missed a very important part. They make you think that the storage is set by default to use the $_SESSION variable but never specify that you should setup the storage before. The answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347123/new-parse-com-php-api-currentuser-not-giving-back-a-user) is what you where looking for:

```
session_start();

// Init parse: app_id, rest_key, master_key
ParseClient::initialize('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz');

// [!] Set session storage
ParseClient::setStorage( new ParseSessionStorage() );
```

Hope it helps anyone.