# Parse.com PHP doesn't keep user in session after signup or login

Tags: php, parse-platform

So I'm using Parse.com with PHP for my user system but it doesn't work as expected. When I call the `signUp()` method the new user is successfully saved in Parse DB and is logged in but if I navigate to another page `ParseUser::getCurrentUser()` doesn't seem to fetch the current user. The same thing happens with the `ParseUser::logIn()` method. Here's part of my code:

```
<?php

            require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 

            use Parse\ParseClient;

            ParseClient::initialize('*, *, *');

            use Parse\ParseUser;
            use Parse\ParseException;
            use Parse\ParseSessionStorage;

            function showForm() {
                echo "
                <form action='user.php' method='POST'>
                    Όνομα (χωρίς #)<br />
                    <input type='text' name='name' required><br /><br />
                    Κωδικός πρόσβασης<br />
                    <input type='password' name='password' required><br /><br />
                    <input type='submit' name='login' value='Σύνδεση'> <input type='submit' name='register' value='Εγγραφή'>
                </form>
                ";
            }
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
                if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
                    try {
                        $user = ParseUser::logIn($_POST['name'], $_POST['password']);
                        echo "<a href='add.php'>Continue</a>";
                        $currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();
                        echo $currentUser->getUsername();
                    } catch (ParseException $error) {
                        echo "Error: " . $ex->getCode() . " " . $ex->getMessage();
                        showForm();
                    }
                } else if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
                    $user = new ParseUser();
                    $user->set("username", $_POST['name']);
                    $user->set("password", $_POST['password']);

                    try {
                        $user->signUp();
                        echo "Εγγραφήκατε επιτυχώς!";
                        $currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();
                        echo $currentUser->getUsername();
                    } catch (ParseException $ex) {
                        echo "Error: " . $ex->getCode() . " " . $ex->getMessage();
                        showForm();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                showForm();
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't seem to fetch the current user", does it fetch anything? Note that it's not likely to be relevant but you should really be terminating your input fields, e.g. `<input type='text' name='name' required />`. It's currently not valid HTML.

Comment: How would I check? The script dies at that point.

Comment: In that case, add a general `catch` after `catch (ParseException $error)` and see what went wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't catch anything. I told you, the registration/login gets successfully done but the issue is the session.

Comment: Here is a more detailed explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347123/new-parse-com-php-api-currentuser-not-giving-back-a-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot to put `session_start();` after `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` in every page I needed the session.